# jQuery - Swap DIV on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, swap, mouseenter

Is it possible to perform a swap or show/hide when hovering over a div?

For example, say I have two DIVs:

```
<div id="box1">content of box 1</div>
<div id="box1-hover">you are hovering on this box</div>
```

Box 1 should be displayed on the page, with  box1-hover hidden, then, when you hover over box 1, box1-hover should become visable **OVER THE TOP OF IT** (so it basically looks like a swap).  Then when you mouseout, box1-hover becomes hidden again.

Is this do-able?  If so, can someone demonstrate with a jsfiddle?

Thanks
Zach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  You will want to investigate [.mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), [.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/), and [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).  The code below should get you most of the way there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#box1").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#box1-hover").show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $("#box1-hover").hide();
    });
});
```

For CSS you will want to understand [z-indices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index) and [absolute positioning inside relative positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).  The Z index indicates how "high" in the page an element is (think of things as coming towards you).  An absolutely positioned item in a relatively positioned item is absolutely positioned against *the parent* and not the page.

The CSS needed:

```
#box1 {
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#box1-hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Note that the div for `box1-hover` is nested in `box1` in this instance

[see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cJufv/3/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain perfectly - when box1-hover is displayed, it should be over the top of the first box, in the same space.

Comment: @Zach - yeah, I realized that as you were leaving the comment.  Have edited my fiddle and added needed code here.

Comment: thanks very much.  am learning jQuery as we speak so this help is invaluble!

Answer (score 1):

look:
http://jsfiddle.net/uQuTt/